# Problem encountered when sending binary blob (with XML file)to client side

Tags: javascript, xml, binary, blob, transform

The server sends me an object which contains the byte[] array of a blob(with XML content in it). Java Spring transforms this byte array into an base64 format so finally on client side I will get an base64 data of a blob.

The response that I get from server:

RESPONSE FROM SERVER :  {content: "base64BlobHere"}
On client side I make a request to get the xml content

```
getXmlContent() {

//makeRequestService.getXmlContent is only an observable that is making a GET Request

this.makeRequestService.getXmlContent.subscribe((response)=> {

    const file = new FileReader();
    file.onload = res => {
      //Here I should be able to read the content of the file as text/string.
       console.log(res.target);
     };

     file.readAsText(b64ToBlob(response.content));
    })
}
```

To read from the file I've tried transforming the base64 content into a blob to get my data.

```
 b64ToBlob(b64Data, contentType = "text/xml", sliceSize = 512) {

    const byteCharacters = atob(b64Data);

    const byteArrays = [];

    for (let offset = 0; offset < byteCharacters.length; offset += sliceSize) {

      const slice = byteCharacters.slice(offset, offset + sliceSize);

      const byteNumbers = new Array(slice.length);

      for (let i = 0; i < slice.length; i++) {

        byteNumbers[i] = slice.charCodeAt(i);

      }

      const byteArray = new Uint8Array(byteNumbers);

      byteArrays.push(byteArray);

    }

    const blob = new Blob(byteArrays, { type: contentType });

    return blob;
  }
```

I think I am missing something and I try to read the data from that xml file. I would be glad to receive some suggestions on how to approach this issue.

Comment: Can you share us Blob data or what is the  console.log result before and after b64Toblob functiion

Comment: Hello, in response.content I will get the next base64 value: